# Play youtube videos in vlc in 1080p quality

Tags: video, vlc, youtube

Since neither firefox nor chrome seem to use hardware acceleration for youtube videos I am now trying to play them using vlc. That does work but I am experiencing two problems:

- When I jump to a given position using the slider the playback does not seem to resume normally from that position but it is constantly buffering and then playing a few seconds. Does anybody know why this is?
- Regardless of what the quality setting are the video always plays in 720p quality. Can I somehow force vlc to play in 1080p? I also downloaded livestreamer and interestingly this program also doesn't list 1080p as available for a video that can clearly be played in 1080p via the youtube webpage.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I believe the lack of 1080p is that Youtube uses separate streams for video and audio at that quality (Known as DASH) - there is a way to watch 1080p videos in VLC though: https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/3ijei1/how_to_watch_youtube_above_720p_dash_streams_in/ There's also a desktop youtube application for Linux, see http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/youtube-viewer-complete-youtube-client.html, which may be of interest. There's also various Youtube downloader apps, maybe you could download the videos first, and then watch them ? About the seeking issue in VLC: I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the useful tips! I had a look at the youtube-viewer and that seems to be a quite handy tool to watch youtube videos. For the moment I'll stick to that. :) The seeking issue in VLC puzzles me... i didn't see that with the other players that I've tried.

Comment: Are you sure the graphics driver you use has hardware acceleration? Which driver?

Answer (score 0):

You should try SMPlayer. It supports what you are looking for.

To do so, follow these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
sudo apt update
sudo apt install smplayer
```

**Resources:**

- https://linoxide.com/install-use-youtube-dl-ubuntu/
- https://www.imaginelinux.com/install-smplayer-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to play Youtube videos in SMPlayer. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)